# i need to display the collection a data which is not in collection b using node js mongo db

Tags: node.js, mongodb

My question about mongodb query.I know in MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table2)
```

But I need it in mongo
 following are the database collection

```
A:{
       {id:4, name:"BB", age:1},
       {id:3, name:"cc", age:3},
       {id:2, name:"SS", age:5}, 
} 
B:{
       id:4, name:"BB", age:1},
       {id:3, name:"cc", age:3} 
}
```

I need to display only `{id:2, name:"SS", age:5}`

```
db.a.find({},function(err, data){ 
res.render(a.ejs, {data:data}) 
});
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you'd need to have two collections with the same schema? In most scenarios you wouldn't want to do that unless there was a very specific edge reason.

Comment: Which version of the [MongoDB NodeJS driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) are you using? The query can be done using Aggregation - are you sure to use aggregations?